# Looking for part number of a 9-pin connector

Tags: identification, connector

Here is the 9 pin connector. For reference: it is used for Li-ion battery packs. In the datasheet it is given as 90SR 9WMN. Searching for the same, I could not find anything similar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this website to search something similar : http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=circular_conn&fl=000000030000200000002013000-15c-|6|1||||

Comment: @citizen: thank you for the plug.

Comment: @AKHIL HEGDE, what is the exact [pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch), please?

Comment: @Davide Andrea : So if you've found it, can you share with us the plug reference number, for our curiosity ?

Comment: @citizen:  No, I am waiting for OP to tell us the pitch.